# Get users who don't have sent email MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

My DB has the following tables,

```
User (id, name)
EmailTemplate (id, subject, template)
EmailTrack (id, user_id, email_template_id)
```

I want to get the users who don't have sent specific email_template yet by the SQL query.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: "I want" is not a question, it's a demand. We're not a free code-writing service. Instead we'd like to _help_ you solve a specific issue. Have you got a problem with implementing this? What difficulty are you facing? (Hint: "I haven't tried yet" is not a valid difficulty.) It should be a relatively straightforward query using JOINs and possible IN or NOT IN subqueries. There are a couple of ways to do it. If you google generically for "find IDs which are not in another table" you'll get the general idea.

Comment: Hint: `LEFT JOIN`,`NOT EXIST`, `NOT IN`

Comment: "user is neither a reserved table, nor a reserved keyword" yes it is @Strawberry https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-U

Comment: @RaymondNijland The reserved ones have a little (R) next to them, so you know they're 'Reserved' - `mysql> CREATE TABLE user(user SERIAL PRIMARY KEY); -- Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.17 sec)`

Comment: i know @Strawberry `user` will be properly reserved in the future

Comment: @RaymondNijland  Anyway, the point is IT'S NOT RESERVED

Comment: true @Strawberry i can't deny that.. i tend to avoid indentififer names which names are part of MySQL statements.. like `user` is in `ALTER USER ...` maybe that's why i called `user` a reserved keyword

Comment: @RaymondNijland I think you simply made a mistake. It happens.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `not exists` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   user u
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   emailtemplate temp
                   JOIN   emailtrack track ON temp.id = track.email_template_id
                   WHERE  template = 'some_specific_template' AND
                          track.user_id = u.id)
```